# Google Pytype in Vim

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, neovim

Is there a current way of getting [Google's Pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype) to run in Vim 8/Neovim?

I can get Microsoft's [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) working easily with [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) but my team uses Pytype instead.

Has anyone attempted any integration?

My searches have brought me nothing, but it's hard to imagine I'm the first person ever to want this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

coc-pyright has added Pytype support, you can enable it by [python.linting.pytypeEnabled](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/blob/fbdb7e258352f1e81fa92c8940b2998f59a0c632/package.json#L790).

Comment: Does that mean that you should add this to your config.yaml file? `python.linting.pytypeEnabled: true`? Presumably you also need to do something to install pytype do you?

Comment: @LondonRob yes, you need to install pytype by yourself, and enable it by `python.linting.pytypeEnabled` in your coc-settings.json.